# Limit undefined reference errors to only direct dependencies

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I develop on Linux with projects shared by other people and using qt creator.

Problem is that I get many times linking errors, especially because this happens:

> libA uses libB -> libA must link to libB
>
> libC uses libA -> libC must link to both libA and libB
>
> appZ uses libC -> appZ must link to libC, libA and libB

For me the ideal would be that in my appZ .pro file I have to write just: "link to libC" and then automatically it gets the other dependencies.

This because it often happens that someone changes the dependencies of one of the libs and lots of hard to fix linking problem come to say hello..

Is there any way to set qt creator in a way to specify only the most direct dependencies, and if yes, is there any drawback? some other alternative?

I was investigating the linking flag `--no-undefined` but still have not understood if this would help me.

[Edit] Just to clarify, problem is that if 100 apps use libC, it becomes a big problem if libC or one of its dependencies must link to a new library.. all the applications must be changed or they have linking problems. I am just looking for a way to limit this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well linking is a wide area of topic and often requires huge time and experience to understand everything.

To answer your question, no one changes dependencies of libraries or so files overnight. Even if they change, they provide the previous version along with new version and  they provide backward compatibility with previous version of that library (meaning the old api will work). If they have added some new dependencies to provide new support or features, they provide in detail which new so files you need and how to build that new library.

In many cases, if you do not want any new support, use old version of that library itself. But usually the new library has some bug fixes and its better to go for new version.

We use libraries to reduce our workload but it is surprising to see that we increase some workload to build third party libraries, keeping track of changes and bugs in these libraries, resolving linking error etc. Sadly dealing with libraries is not as easy compare in case in Java or npm.

What I do is write a script in Linux which keeps track of everything.But that script is itself not automated but it reduces much of my workload. I think you can also do something similar.

> Just to clarify, problem is that if 100 apps use libC, it becomes a big problem if libC or one of its dependencies must link to a new library.. all the applications must be changed or they have linking problems. I am just looking for a way to limit this problem

It is easy in this case, just build your new library in your build machine , and provide so file path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I understand this is not easy as said, but as mentioned earlier, dealing with libraries is not as easy compare in case in Java or npm. You may also have to make some edits in the script which you use to maintain your build. I don't see any shortcut.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, I am not speaking about third part libraries. Me and friends have a code base composed by tens of small size libraries, and because of time, nobody provides backward compatibility and so on.. What I mean is this: if A depends from B and C and A is used by 100 applications, if you add D to A, all the 100 applications must be modified.

Comment: Well if you guys can add me in your project , may be i can deal with it

Comment: thank you very much for your availability! at the moment is still not public, but we'll release it in the future. However, yep, I was looking for some shortcuts.. maybe some linker flag or some already ready script that checks lib dependencies!

Comment: Bro you have to write your own script for this @Saturnu

Comment: yep, I was hoping there was already some tool to reduce the amount of scripts to write